# MongoDB Vs Sqlserver for an Asp.Net MVC3 Application

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, mongodb-.net-driver

I am building a website with Asp.Net MVC 3 and C# ,I am pretty comfortable with Sqlserver but thinking of going with MongoDB since i am assuming it will be cheaper for me to host(free ?) the site.
My website stores tons of user records with a Title and Contents along with some other data for that logged in user.I would like to have the requirement to do a full text search on the Content.I am wondering if MongoDB is suitable for this requirement.

Thanks  in advance !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my experience with MongoDB there are a few things to think about.

MongoDB is a document based database, using the standard driver from 10gen you can serialize POCO classes directly or store you data as an untyped document.

This does bring a great deal of flexibility as you can store a complete record about a user store and retrieve it without having to normalise the data as you would with SQL Server.

That being said the Full text capabilities of MongoDB are very limited compared to that of a SQL Server, see the link below for details of how to do a basic full text search in Mongo.

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Full+Text+Search+in+Mongo

MongoDB really come into its own when retrieving data as it is attempts to store the DB in memory, this makes getting data from it pretty quick.

10gen are also implementing Linq support directly into the driver which makes querying Mongo just that bit easier when getting started. Also you could use FluentMongo (https://github.com/craiggwilson/fluent-mongo) which sits on top of the 10gen driver and is slightly more advanced in terms of its Linq support.

My experience with MongoDB has been very positive and intend to use it in the future for other client projects.

With hosting I would imagine you would want at least console access so that you can start the DB service and manage any backups. Failing that you could try something like https://mongohq.com/home which seems to provide online hosting of mongo db.

I hope some of this is helpful

Comment: Since full text search is very limited in MongoDB, does that mean my search on Content field will not be that effecient and fast ?

Comment: It will still be fast returning the data, however that does require you to do extra processing when creating the document in mongo. Their recommendation is that you parse the strings you wish to do a full text search on and store them in one field. So really you are doing the work that would be done by the SQL full text search Catalogue.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on your data structure. MongoDB is a document oriented DB. It is faster than MS Sql Server for "plain data structure". But it still has big problems with "join" functionality.

If you want to try out good No-SQL database for a .NET project RavenDB could be a good choice as well - http://ravendb.net/ It is as fast as Mongo and it doesn't have many problems of document databases (for example it has pretty good way to work with joins). But! it's not free:)

If you need to implement full text search Solr http://lucene.apache.org/solr/ is very interesting and useful instrument for this. We used it on several projects with Solr.NET library http://code.google.com/p/solrnet/ Good start tutorial is here - http://crazorsharp.blogspot.co.nz/2010/01/full-text-search-using-solr-lucene-and.html